# Is there some result for missing data MLEs?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, missing-data

So I'm trying to figure out the MLEs for parameters $\alpha$ and $\pi$, when

$L(\alpha, \pi)=[e^{-n\alpha} e^{-e^{-\alpha} \sum{x_j} }] \times \pi^m(1-\pi)^{n-m}$

and if all data exists, then $\hat{\alpha}=\log(\bar{X}).$

Is there some result that I can use to infer $\hat{\alpha}$ in this missing data case, if I know what $\hat{\alpha}$ is with fully existing data? Can I also find $\pi$ this way?

Comment: In the case of missing data Expectation Maximization is the appropriate method to estimate the parameters.

Comment: @F.Alanazi I have not been taught that.

Comment: It is very simple and the second step (maximum step or M step) is the maximum likelihood step.